# Use React.forwardRef with a ref type based on a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have the following component:

```
interface Props {
  as: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap
  // ... other props
}

const A = React.forwardRef<any, Props>((props, ref) => {
   // ... implementation
})
```

This component will render an HTMl element based on the `as` prop, and the caller can pass in a ref to attach to the element. Currently, I'm using `any` for the type of the ref, but ideally, I'd want that to be the actual HTMLElement subtype based on the `as` prop that's being passed in. How can I do that? I can likely get the actual tag type from `HTMLElementTagNameMap`, but I'm just not sure how to write that into the function signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible (although there exists a workaround).

### Why it is not possible

You need generics to "bind" together the two type parameters provided to `forwardRef`. Consider the following code:

```js
interface Props<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> {
  as: T;
  // ... other props
}

const A = React.forwardRef<HTMLElementTagNameMap[T], Props<T>>(
  (props, ref) => {
    return null;
  }
);
```

The declaration of `T` parameter is missing at the component level. There is nowhere you can put such declaration. This is a limitation of `React.forwardRef`.

### Workaround

As a workaround, you can ditch `forwardRef` and add the ref to your `Props` interface:

```js
interface Props<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap> {
  as: T;
  theRef: React.Ref<HTMLElementTagNameMap[T]>
  // ... other props
}

function A<T extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(props: Props<T>) {
  const { as, theRef, /*...*/ } = props;
  return null;
}
```

[Example in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgAUcwBnAHgBU4kAHnWoATDnADWSAJ4RMcABI8AsgBkAogBskIJLR4oA5gDkUu5SjAA+OAG9ycOCg4AuODwqOYACyTJMAPxuyOgwAHT+XEpqWjp6MAYmZkgWYADaPAC6Vp5wAPR5cGHFcBA+9HBg7BzkAL6UmACu1BjAENRwAIK8-EJ6YpIycooqGtq6+kam5pZWABRVEJxubEvcPFYAlHYOcGjtHPC2ThwANHDl-vkAVMVh14W1cAC8ldW5RDCNUB3UjZqaCj1chNFowNoddQCMxgbRzbb2Rz7aiHOBEeSvEIYMKNDh+JCYKKjADKYBQ1FiExg8z+AM2HyQXx+cC4nROzwARCJgAA3DkXXz+Z62dFPPI5OrkIA).